# JS Object destructuring/restructuring is unsafe if values are undefined and "in" operator is used on the new object. How to get around this?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring, ecmascript-next, in-operator

Consider the following code. I know it's a bit contrived, but it's a simplification of a more complex problem that I ran into while writing a custom react hook for debouncing using lodash:

```
import { debounce } from 'lodash';

function getDebounce(fn, delay, { maxWait, trailing }) {
  return debounce(fn, delay, {leading: false, maxWait, trailing }) 
}

// succeeds, but this debounce will never fire because `trailing` is false
const debouncedFn = getDebounce(() => {}, 300, { maxWait: 500 })
```

You might expect this to work, and that this is equivalent to `trailing` being set to whatever the default in the library is, but that's not true.

In `lodash.debounce`, the `in` [operator is used to determine if that option is present](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/debounce.js#L89). That check ends up flipping the default `trailing` option from `true` to `false`.

This happens because:

```
'foo' in { foo: undefined } // true
'foo' in { } // false
```

This is a really nasty potential bug for any code or dependency that uses the `in` operator under the hood. How do we get around this? How do we program defensively? Should there be an eslint rule for this? **I understand that there's various ways to fix my particular example, I can think of a few** (if you want to see a full example of the bug I fell into, see [issue#4973](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4973)). The problem that I'm trying to solve for is to not run into this kind of issue where it feels like the language has failed. I'd be happy if the `in` operator went away, but that's not going to happen.

Comment: `function getDebounce(fn, delay { maxWait, trailing }) {` will be a SyntaxError. Did you mean to add a comma after `delay`?

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with the destructuring at all? You're not making use of `maxWait` and `trailing` as separate values anyway.

Why not just something like this...

```js
function getDebounce(fn, delay, options = {}) {
  return debounce(fn, delay, { ...options, leading: false }) 
}
```

The order of `...options` and `leading: false` determines if you want to allow `options` to overwrite `leading`. Put `...options` last if you do want it to overwrite

Comment: I'm aware of that option, as previously stated. I simplified the problem to convey the point of the unexpected behavior. See https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/4973 to understand why I destructured, but that's still beside the point.

Comment: I sometimes prefer to explicitly destructure and reconstruct object. It makes it explicit what the options are.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, if I understand you correctly, you're wondering what kinds of defensive strategies you can employ to prevent the kind of bug you were running into with lodash (lodash was treating `{trailing: undefined}` different from `{}`). For those looking for more context, [here's](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/e0029485ab4d97adea0cb34292afb6700309cf16/debounce.js#L89) the line of lodash's source code that caused this issue for the OP. I'm going to go out on a limb and say that this behavior was probably unintentional in lodash.

The difficulty in answering this, is that there *are* valid use cases for distinguishing between a value being set to undefined/null vs a valid not being present (an options argument usually isn't one of those cases though). For example, if you want to represent a mapping of all usernames in a system to their emails, you might make "undefined" mean that a particular user has not provided an email, while a username not being present means they're not in the system.

Now, there's two ways to go about answering your question: from the point of view of an API consumer, and the pointer of view of the API creator (like lodash, or some internal API you're making).

So, what defensive strategies are available from the point of view of an API consumer? None. what you ran into shouldn't happen. It broke your expectation. An options object should not behave that way. This is Lodash's fault. Sometimes APIs we consume have weird and unpredictable behaviors, and there's not much we can do to prepare against other people's bugs. The best that we can do is test thoroughly to make sure we catch these kinds of issues.

What defensive strategies are available from the point of view of an API producer? There really isn't much that can be done here either, because, like mentioned before, there are valid reasons for distinguishing between undefined and non-existent members. The developer in this scenario simply used the wrong tool for the job. The best that can be done here is to educate developers when to use which tools. For example, if Lodash had simply used object destructing and default values, the tool meant for the job they were doing, then this issue wouldn't have happened. (this tool might not have been available to them if they're coding in es5).

Sorry to give such an unsatisfying answer, but that's the truth. ... unless you want to program in a more radical way in javascript where you never allow a distinction to be made between undefined and non-present, in which case I'm sure you could come up with a set of rules that would prevent most of these problems. You might even be able to es-lint them. And who knows, maybe that is a better way to program.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful response! I assume that lodash's option parsing is ancient, and part of why it's still written that way. Re: email/username example: In my .js systems, I rely on either null/empty-string/object/array to indicate emptiness. To me if something is `undefined`, there isn't a var/prop at that named reference—unset/not defined. But since js has both `undefined` and `null` (not to mention other wacky falsy primitives like NaN and -0) , unlike other languages (python) I would expect that null would be the standard for distinguishing "this is intentionally empty".

Comment: I've heard of people coding in a similar way, where they try to always prefer things like null over undefined to prevent these kinds of errors. From my experience, it seems more common to just treat undefined and null as the same thing, and allow API users to use whichever they want. That's why its become common to make an exception with the "always use triple equals" rule when comparing against null - because  `x == null` is a convenient way to check if its either null or undefined, without caring which it is.

Comment: One reason for treating undefined like null, is it makes iterating over object properties simpler. `Object.keys({x:undefined})` would still give back ['x'] even though you don't intend for it to be set, while explicitly using `delete` on an object would actually get rid of the attribute.